# Supercuspidal representation from compact induction

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, p-adic-number-theory

Note: this is a homework problem. Any hints would be great.

Consider the group $G=GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ and an open subgroup $K$ that is compact modulo center. Suppose we have a smooth representation $\rho$ of $K$ which we compactly induce to obtain a representation $\pi$ (with space $V$) of $G$, and suppose this $\pi$ is supercuspidal. I need to show that $\pi$ has no $K$-fixed vectors.

I have some attempt, but I am unable to take it forward. So suppose there is a non-zero $K$-fixed vector $v$. Then for every $k \in K$, $\pi(k)v-v$ is zero. Now if we could find a subgroup $N$ contained in $K$ where $N$ is the unipotent subgroup of some parabolic subgroup $P=MN$, then I am thinking we could use this to show that the Jacquet module corresponding to this $N$ is not trivial? But I am unclear on how to show that elements of the form $\pi(n) v - v$ do not span the whole of $V$, nor do I know if we can actually find a subgroup $N$ as suggested.

Comment: It seems to be true in general (as long as the space you induce from is irreducible). Are you sure the supercuspidal assumption is needed?

Comment: @Oven Is irreducibility necessary here? If the representation we induce from is irreducible, then it is easy to show that the compactly induced representation is supercuspidal. All we need to do is define one matrix coefficient that is supported on K. But here, I am already telling you that the representation is supercuspidal, and only interested in the absence of K-fixed vectors.

Comment: Irreducibility may not be necessary.

Comment: I suppose you want to assume that $\rho$ is not the trivial representation of $K$?